# Is Maven or Eclipse responsible for deploying a war file?

Tags: eclipse, web-deployment, m2e, eclipse-luna

I'm using m2e and Eclipse Luna to build a servlet application.  'maven package' produces a project war file but I can't get beyond that.  The war file is not being deployed no matter what I try.

I could just copy the war file manually but I'd like to do it the maven-way or the Eclipse-way which ever is appropriate.

I'm guessing some part of the setup is missing but I've spent two days trying everything I can find on the subject and no joy.

Who is responsible for doing the deployment, Maven or Eclipse?

And, most importantly, how should you deploy from an m2e/Eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here.  Hopefully, this will help future generations.

The root cause of my problem was that I did not realize that Eclipse was deploying to the `<TOMCAT_HOME>/wtpwebapps`  directory not `<TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps`.
To deploy all that is necessary is to start the Tomcat server from the Eclipse servers tab.  Maven has nothing to do with it.  I should note that you can deploy with Maven but it requires some config.  With Eclipse you just start the server and Eclipse handles everything else.